# How to enforce OnceOnlyController when called through ModuleController multiple times

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

Lets say i have a SimpleController that i use as a SubController for ModuleControllers. In it i have a OnceOnlyController (among other things).

Next, lets say that i have a Loop->RandomController combo that has multiple Controller options. Some of those options have ModuleControllers that point to the above mentioned SubController with the OnceOnlyController.

If the Subcontroller is called from different options of the Loop->RandomController combo, then the OnceOnlyController is not enforced.

How can i enforce the OnceOnlyController in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Its a Once Only Controller and hence its behavior is in such a manner. However, there is a loophole in this. Nest the first Simple Controller under another Simple Controller (any other controller is also good enough for this. It just needs to be nested under a parent).

**Your approximately current Scenario:**

Both Module Controllers refer to the 1st Simple Controller

[image]

**Suggested Scenario**

Put the Simple Controller under another Controller

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

The behavior of Once Only controller persists across multiple iterations without having any side effects of nesting the 1st simple controller.

---

**WORD OF CAUTION**

> Interactions between multiple controllers can yield complex behavior. This is particularly true of the Random Controller. Experiment before you assume what results any given interaction will give

Source: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually found a different solution. Instead of OnceOnlyController i use IfController where i check for a variable (lets call it "controllerCalled"). At the begining of the thread a use a JSR233 Sampler to set a variable "controllerCalled" to false and in the IFcontroller i set that variable to true. I works perfectly

Comment: My understanding was you needed onceonly controller as part of you scenario since your question was to "enforce onceonly controller". So hadn't suggested that option of removing the controller itself.. anyways, if you set variable to true within IF once, how does it get triggered during subsequent calls further down the script? Are you making it false again elsewhere?

Comment: I want to call it once per thread. At the begining of the thread i set it to false, then when it comes to the IFcontroller i set it to true. Then it cannot be called again in the thread. Once the thread completes and a new thread is created, it is set to false again (but i think that this step is unneccesery because variables should be threadscoped)